# How to pass dynamically created check box value as a function parameter?

Tags: java, javascript, jstl

I have written a jsp file to retrieve data model from servlet. Data is coming from the name 'list'.
I'm drawing table rows to each row of data that is passed. And there is a check box which shows value of field 'ob'. It is the only value that can be edited. Finally Request button is appears in each row to call a java-script function.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="queue" varStatus="varStatus">

<td>${queue.name}</td>
<td>${queue.age }</td>
<td>${queue.gender}</td>
<td width="50"><c:choose>
<c:when test="${queue.ob == 1}"><input name="obVal" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" />
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<input name="obVal" type="checkbox" value="" /></c:otherwise></c:choose>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button"  class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Request"       onclick="requestForDischarge('${queue.name}',**VALUE OF CHECKBOX 1 OR 2**);"/></td>

</c:forEach>
```

The method requestForDischarge is taking relevant queue.name value and value of check box value as 1 or 0. How can i pass that value?

Comment: Data is shown fine. Passing the checkbox value is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Name your checkbox with queue id .

```
<td>${queue.name}</td>
<td>${queue.age }</td>
<td>${queue.gender}</td>
<td width="50">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${queue.ob == 1}">
       <input name="${queue.id}" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <input name="${queue.id}" type="checkbox" value="" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" 
     class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Request"
     onclick="requestForDischarge('${queue.name}','${queue.id}');"/>
</td>

</c:forEach>
```

Pass the queue id to your function then.

On your javascript put something like :

```
document.getElementById(queueId).value
```

to get the value .

hope this will help , happy coding :)